# list index out of range,python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a question, that is, I have 1D list like this:

```
List_A = []
```

and I also have another list, something like this:

```
List_B = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)]
```

Now I try to use:

```
for i in range(3):
List_A[i] = List_B[i][2]
```

which means, I want take every last (3rd) number from List_B to List_A, but it is said "index out of range", so what is the problem? Thank you very much for your helping

I know the append method but I think I can't use it, because my code is under a loop, the value in List_B changes in every step,something like:

```
List_A = []

for i in range(5):
List_B = [(i*1,i*2,i*3),(i*2,i*3,i*4),(i*3,i*4,i*5)]  
    for j in range(3):
        List_A[j] = List_B[j][2]
```

that is to say, if I use append method, the List_A will enlarge to 15 element size, but I need refresh value in every i loop.

Comment: `List_A = [3]` doesn't create a list with a length of 3, if that's what you think it did. It creates a list with a single element, whose value is 3.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the complete questions and not answers. Please add relevant examples too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with `List_A` which has only one value. Here you are trying to change the values for the indexes `1` and `2` of the list where there is none. So you get the error.

Use [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead after declaring `List_A` as `[]`

```
for i in range(3):
     List_A.append(List_B[i][2])
```

This can be done in a single list-comp as

```
List_A = [i[2] for i in List_B]
```

---

Post edit-

Put the initialization right after the first loop

```
for i in range(5):
    List_A = []                          # Here 
    List_B = [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)]  
    for j in range(3):
        List_A.append(List_B[j][2])
    # Do other stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

This loop is the problem

```
for i in range(3):
    List_A[i] = List_B[i][2]
```

You can only access `List_A[0]`, the rest of the values of `i` are out of range. If you are trying to *populate* the list, you should use `append`

```
List_A = []
for i in range(3):
    List_A.append(List_B[i][2])
```

Or more Pythonic use a list comprehension

```
List_A = [i[2] for i in List_B]
```